# NullPointerException SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

I am trying to get a list of information from my database and display that into a custom listview.  I already have my DatabaseHelper, Fragment, and Adapter setup.  Here are the errors I am receiving:

```
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:110)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.<init>(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:130)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.<init>(WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.java:35)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.rcd.mypr.Workouts.WorkoutsFragment.onCreateView(WorkoutsFragment.java:36)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-29 13:36:52.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my WorkoutsDatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.rcd.mypr.Workouts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class WorkoutsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {


    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "workoutsDatabase.sqlite";
    private static final String WORKOUTS_TABLE = "workouts";

    // Workouts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_WORKOUT_NAME = "workout_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_LAST_NAME = "hero_last_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_FIRST_NAME = "hero_first_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_MIDDLE_NAME = "hero_middle_name";
    private static final String KEY_HERO_DESCRIPTION = "hero_description";
    private static final String KEY_DATE_ADDED = "date_added";
    private static final String KEY_WORKOUT = "workout";
    private static final String KEY_MEASUREMENT = "measurement";
    private static final String KEY_PHOTO = "photo";



    public WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public Cursor getWorkoutNames() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(WORKOUTS_TABLE, new String[] {"_id", "workout_name"}, null, null, null,
                null, KEY_WORKOUT_NAME + " ASC");
        return cursor;

    }


 }
```

And Lastly, here is my WorkoutsFragment.java

```
package com.rcd.mypr.Workouts;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.rcd.mypr.R;


public class WorkoutsFragment extends Fragment {

    WorkoutsDatabaseHelper db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ListView listContent;
    private int position;
    Cursor cursor;
    private Context mContext;
    WorkoutsAdapter workoutsAdapter;

    public WorkoutsFragment(){}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        db = new WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(mContext);
        mContext = getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_workouts, container, false);

        listContent = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        // Create the Adapter
        workoutsAdapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(mContext, cursor);

        // Set the adapter to ListView
        listContent.setAdapter(workoutsAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }



    private void initViews(){
        //Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"Roboto-Light.ttf");
    }

    private void addItemsToList(){
        Cursor cursor = db.getWorkoutNames();
        Log.d("history.java", "finished Cursor cursor = db.getAllLogs();");
        String[] from = {"_id", "workouts_name"};
        int[] to = {R.id.tv_id, R.id.tv_label};
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.single_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
        listContent.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        workoutsAdapter = new WorkoutsAdapter(mContext, cursor);
        listContent.setAdapter(workoutsAdapter);
    }


}
```

If there is anything else you need to see please let me know.

Comment: Which line is #110? (Your exception tells you that's where the problem is at)

Comment: I believe its } based off this link
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/readystatesoftware/sqliteasset/SQLiteAssetHelper.java

Comment: That line will **never** throw an NPE. You should check again. Look at your logcat output and trace the NPE back to it's source. Each line will show you the line number that had problems and you can work back from there.

Comment: @vjdhama, how can you tell its that line?  The only line number I see referring to the fragments file is line 36 which is
db = new WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(mContext);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the `onCreateView()`-method of your `Fragment`.
You initialize your `WorkoutsDatabaseHelper` with a `null` `Context`.

```
    db = new WorkoutsDatabaseHelper(mContext);
    mContext = getActivity();
```

Switch these two lines and try again...